# Is this sum of reciprocals of zeta zeros correct?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

I am trying to find or get a numerical approximation of
$$ \sum_{\rho \text{ non-trivial zeros of } \zeta} \frac{1}{\rho} $$

In [The Riemann Hypothesis: Arithmetic and Geometry](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~lagarias/doc/mt-holyoke-rev.pdf) Lagarias gives the identity:

$$\hat{\zeta}(s) := \pi^{-\frac{s}{2}} \Gamma(\frac{s}{2})\zeta(s)$$

$$ \frac{\hat{\zeta}^\prime(s)} {\hat{\zeta}(s)} = \frac{d}{ds} [ \log \hat{\zeta}(s) ] = -\frac{1}{s} - \frac{1}{s-1} + {\sum_{\rho \text{ zeros of } \zeta }}^\prime \frac{1}{s-\rho} \qquad(1)$$

where the prime indicates the zeros must be summed in pairs $\rho,1-\rho$

> Q1 Does the last sentence mean that the sum is over the non-trivial zeros?

Maple gives:
$$\lim_{s \to 0} {\sum_{\rho \text{ zeros of } \zeta }}^\prime \frac{1}{s-\rho} = -\gamma + \frac{1}{2}  \log\left(\pi\right) + \log\left(2\right) - 1$$

<strike>If the above result is correct, is it true that:</strike>

$$ \sum_{\rho \text{ non-trivial zeros of } \zeta} \frac{1}{\rho} = \gamma - \frac{1}{2}  \log\left(\pi\right) - \log\left(2\right) + 1 $$

**EDIT** As Micah Milinovich kindly answerd the above is wrong.

Trying to save the quiestion, is it true that:
$$ \sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{\rho (1{-}\rho)} =  \gamma - \frac{1}{2} \log\left(\pi\right) - \log\left(2\right) + 1  $$

Assuming RH $1-\rho = \bar{\rho}$ and the LHS is $\sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{|\rho|^2}$

According to [RH Equivalence 5.3](http://aimath.org/pl/rhequivalences). $$\sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{\rho (1{-}\rho)}=\sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{|\rho|^2} = 2 + \gamma - \log 4\pi$$.

And the constants still don't match.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your modified question, according to Mathematica:

$$ \lim_{s\to 0} \left(\frac{\hat{\zeta}'}{\hat{\zeta}}(s)+\frac{1}{s}\right) = -\frac{\gamma}{2} + \tfrac{1}{2}\log(4\pi).$$

This implies that

$${\sum_\rho}'\frac{1}{\rho} = \sum_{\Im \rho >0} \frac{1}{\rho(1-\rho)}= 1 +\frac{\gamma}{2} - \tfrac{1}{2}\log(4\pi). $$

Therefore
$$\sum_{ \rho } \frac{1}{\rho(1-\rho)} = 2 \sum_{\Im \rho >0} \frac{1}{\rho(1-\rho)}= 2 +\gamma - \log(4\pi).$$

Comment: Thank you. I made a computational mistake and now agree with your answer.

Comment: Per juan's answer your sum is unconditionally $=\sum_{\rho} \rho^{-1}+\overline{\rho}^{-1}$ (the constant depends if one takes only Im(s)>0 or not). Since on the critical line the terms are equal does this mean the difference of the sums over potential Siegel zeros must vanish unconditionally?

Answer (score 8):

The series $\sum_\rho \rho^{-1}$ over the non-trivial zeros  is not absolutely convergent, this is proved in Davenport p. 80.  But as Davenport says and proves in 
page 81-82  the series converges conditionally provided one groups together
the terms from $\rho$ and its conjugate $\overline{\rho}$. And the value of 
the sum can be given, independently of RH, as the constant $-B$ where
$B = -\frac12 \gamma-1+\frac12\log4\pi$.  (This value was known to Riemann, as Siegel 
says in his paper about the Riemann Nachlass).

Comment: In Lagarias formula the sum is over the non trivial zeros repeated according to its multiplicity. In fact the formula is the Mittag-Leffler expansion of the meromorphic function  $\frac{\hat\zeta'(s)}{\hat\zeta(s)}$ that has poles just at the non-trivial zeros and at 
$0$ and $1$


Comment: Thank you. I made a computational mistake and now agree with Micah's answer.

Comment: Looks like Micah's sum $\sum_{\rho} \rho^{-1}+(1-\rho)^{-1}$ is exactly $\sum_{\rho} \rho^{-1}+\overline{\rho}^{-1}$ (Davenport's $B$ sums only Im(s)>0 and this explains the factor of $2$. Since on the critical line the terms are equal does this mean the difference of the sums over potential Siegel zeros must vanish unconditionally?

Comment: In fact the two sums are equal  $\sum_\rho(\rho^{-1}+(1-\rho)^{-1})=
\sum_\rho (\rho^{-1}+\overline{\rho}^{-1})$. But I (or Davenport)
am speaking about $\zeta(s)$. The case of $L(\chi,s)$ is a little
more complicate. In this case the zeros are symmetric with respect
to the line $\sigma=\frac12$ but not respect the real axis.

The determination of the constant $B(\chi)$ is recent, due to Vorhauer in 2006. Davenport 
do not include it. You must see the book by Montgomery and Vaughan, Chapter 10. In the sum you must consider the zeros of 
$L(s,\chi)$ and those of  $L(s,\overline{\chi})$.



Comment: Thanks for the books, juan. Dumb me, now i see why the 2 sums are equal at the possible zeros whatever they might be.

Answer (score 7):

These identities are not mysterious. They are simply the fact that the Riemann Zeta function has a Weierstrass product like any other meromorphic function of finite exponential order. Note here that $f'/f$ is called logarithmic derivative for a reason;)

Then it follows immediately

1) Yes, the zeros of the completed Riemann zeta function are exactly the nontrivial ones.

2) If RH hold, they come in pairs $\rho = 1/2 \pm \mathrm{i}t$ for $t>0$.

A suggestion for computing the sum:

Let $\Omega_T$ be the boundary of $ -T \leq Im s \leq T$ and $-1/2 < Re s < 3/2$. For an approximation consider the integral
$$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int\limits_{\Omega_T} s^{-1} \frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} d \; s = \sum\limits_{-T \leq Im \rho \leq T} \frac{1}{\rho} + $$
some contribution coming from the poles, which are slightly delicate for $s=0$, since you encounter a double pole. I am pretty sure that you have missed that, and that this is why your computation fails.

Wikipedia tells you that 
$$ \zeta(s) = \frac{2^{s-1}}{s-1}-2^s \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(s\arctan t)}{(1+t^2)^\frac{s}{2}(\mathrm{e}^{\pi\,t}+1)}\,\mathrm{d}t,$$
is pretty convenient for computing $\zeta$ numerically.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** I endorse Juan's answer to the original question. The sum $\displaystyle{\sum_{\rho} \tfrac{1}{|\rho|}}$, running over the non-trivial zeros $\rho$ of $\zeta(s)$, is known to diverge, so at best $\displaystyle{\sum_{\rho} \tfrac{1}{\rho}}$ is conditionally convergent so you cannot re-arrange the terms.

In your second to last displayed equation, you removed the assumption that the sum runs over pairs of zeros $\rho$ and $1-\rho$. So it seems that Lagarias' result can be used to evaluate the sum
$$ \sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{\rho (1{-}\rho)}.$$

As you observed, assuming the Riemann Hypothesis $1-\rho =\overline{\rho}$ for any non-trivial zero $\rho$ of $\zeta(s)$. This implies that

$$ \sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{\rho (1{-}\rho)}=\sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{|\rho|^2}.$$

Comment: Thank you. Computing $\sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{|\rho|^2}$ is equivalent to RH according to http://aimath.org/pl/rhequivalences 5.3. I might be missing something but if RH holds $\sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{\rho (1{-}\rho)}=\sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{|\rho|^2} = 2 + \gamma - \log 4\pi$.